# Calling a method in main thread Does impacts its sub methods

Tags: swift, multithreading, swift3

I am curious if calling a method in

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
}
```

does impact on called method's sub methods other methods called in method that is in main thread for example in below code updateUI method is called in main thread now does main thread impacting updateLabels and updateImages method too?

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       updateUI()
    }
    func updateUI(){
    updateLabels()
    updateImages()
    }
    func updateLabels(){
      label.text = "update text"
}
func updateImages(){
    imageView.image = UIImage(name:"newImage.png")
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Are you asking whether `updateLabels` and `updateImages` are called on the main thread as well?

Comment: yes this is what i am curious about.

Comment: Both methods will be called on the main thread. Why would you think otherwise? You have not created any other dispatch queues other than the main one.

Comment: in actually not yet and now i am really in need of as i have collectionView and there is network call that fetches the data from server and displays it in cell. calls happen data occurs in just 2 seconds but collectionView shows data after 8 seconds i don't know why ..

Comment: performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(self.updateUI), with: nil, waitUntilDone: false)
use this method to call main thread for UI update

Comment: @RonGahlot  not working waitUntilDone:true and false both are taking same time 8 seconds.

Comment: after that you must reload collection view

Comment: mine selector is already in collectionViewCell